# I am getting 200 OK error while loggng into wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

I just migrated my WordPress website. But When I try to login into wp-login.php with the correct credentials it shows this error [image: Attached Screenshot].
I can't access wp-admin
Fixes I tried.

1. Deleting .htaccess file
2. Changing permalinks in the database
3. Increasing memory limit

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Do you have access to the hosting error logs?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I can't find any issue there.

Comment: I have not enough information to help. Try enabling debug in wordpress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ and follow the troubleshooting guide: https://wordpress.org/support/category/troubleshooting/ (the Login Trouble section could be a good starting point). Then edit your question adding all relevant information you find during the process.